# Python List Population with Loop

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble getting the `county` list below to populate with results from my loop. When I print out the results of each iteration along with the index of the item in the list, I see I'm getting an index of 0 each time, indicating that the data is not persisting in the list after each loop. Consequently, when I try to index the `county` loop after the loop is complete, there is no data in it at at all of course, so I get the 'list index out of range error.'

I've researched the "list index out of range" error I keep getting, and I understand that I'm getting it because the `county` list is empty, but why is it empty?

The HTML source code that makes up one entry in the `target_divs` list looks like this:

```
<div class="school-type-list-text">
<div class="table_cell_county"><a href='/alabama/autauga-county'>Autauga County</a></div>
<div class="change_div"></div>
<div class="table_cell_other">7<span> Schools</span></div>
<div class="table_cell_other">1,587<span> Students</span></div>
<div class="table_cell_other">8%<span> Minority</span></div>
<div class="break"></div>
```

Here is my script:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import csv

page1 = 'https://www.privateschoolreview.com/alabama'
alabama = urllib2.urlopen(page1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(alabama, "lxml")
target_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_= "school-type-list-text")

for i in target_divs:
    county = i.find_all("div", class_= "table_cell_county")
    for i in county:
        print i.text
        print county.index(i) 

print county
print county[0]
```

Update after @Software2 advised changing the loop cursor, but I'm still getting the same error:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import csv

page1 = 'https://www.privateschoolreview.com/alabama'

alabama = urllib2.urlopen(page1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(alabama, "lxml")

target_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_= "school-type-list-text")

for div in target_divs:
    counties = div.find_all("div", class_= "table_cell_county")
    for county in counties:
        print county.text
        print counties.index(county) 

print counties
```

Comment: you have two `for` loops that reference `i`

Comment: The OP has pasted the output from the code. Please refrain from editing that.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong can you try this. It seems you are using same i in nested loop

```
for i in target_divs:
    county = i.find_all("div", class_= "table_cell_county")
    for j in county:
        print j.text
        print county.index(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable `i` as two different things in nested loops. So the first one is getting overwritten. Change the second variable name.

Ideally, variable names like `i` are not very descriptive, and make it easy to make mistakes like this. Try something like:

```
for div in target_divs:
    counties = div.find_all("div", class_= "table_cell_county")
    for county in counties:
        print county.text
        print counties.index(county)
```

Comment: Made that change, but `counties` is still not populating. Any additional thoughts? I've updated my code in the above post so you can ensure I followed your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want a list of counties in `counties`. In my opinion, the problem is with the return value of `div.find_all()`, which returns an array of at most one county. To populate counties, try the following approach:

```
counties = []
for div in target_divs:
    county = div.find_all('div', class_= 'table_cell_county')
    for c in county:
        counties.append(c.text.encode('utf-8'))

print counties    # Returns: ['Autauga County', 'Baldwin County', 'Barbour County', 'Bibb County', 'Blount County', 'Bullock County', 'Butler County', 'Calhoun County', 'Chambers County', 'Chilton County', 'Choctaw County', 'Clarke County', 'Clay County', 'Coffee County', 'Colbert County', 'Conecuh County', 'Covington County', 'Crenshaw County', 'Cullman County', 'Dale County', 'Dallas County', 'Dekalb County', 'Elmore County', 'Escambia County', 'Etowah County', 'Greene County', 'Hale County', 'Henry County', 'Houston County', 'Jackson County', 'Jefferson County', 'Lauderdale County', 'Lee County', 'Limestone County', 'Lowndes County', 'Macon County', 'Madison County', 'Marengo County', 'Marion County', 'Marshall County', 'Mobile County', 'Monroe County', 'Montgomery County', 'Morgan County', 'Perry County', 'Pickens County', 'Pike County', 'Randolph County', 'Russell County', 'Saint Clair County', 'Shelby County', 'Sumter County', 'Talladega County', 'Tallapoosa County', 'Tuscaloosa County', 'Walker County', 'Wilcox County', 'Winston County']
print counties[0] # Returns: 'Autauga County'
```

Comment: @SFarkas No problem! Also, it would help others too if you can upvote or mark it as answer :)